# WiX bootstrapper silent install with custom /a argument

Tags: wix, arguments, bootstrapping

Is it possible to initiate a silent installation of a WiX bundle through the use of a command line argument in the format of `/a` or `/arg`?

I'm aware of the [available command line arguments accepted by the wixstdba bootstrapper](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Running-Burn-driven-installer-in-quiet-mode-command-line-parameters-td5913001.html).

Specifically, we need to do this using the argument `/s /v/qn` argument.

**NB:** Executing the bootsrapper with the command line `setup.exe /s /v/qn` actually does initiate a silent install, and I assume this is because the BA interprets the `/s` as equivalent to `-s`.  But since I can't find this behaviour documented anywhere, I am nervous about relying upon it, and would prefer an explicit method for doing this.

**TL;DR**

The reason we would like to support this argument `/format` is due to the automatic upgrade operation of a previous version of the software.  This version of the software launched an automatically downloaded upgrade to itself, which was an InstallShield package, with the switches `/s /v/qn` to launch the MSI as a silent installation.  Those switches are coded into a constant field, so the fact that we are moving from InstallShield to WiX presents this problem.

We would like to replicate this functionality but need a way to translate this set of arguments to either a `-silent` or `-passive` argument, or find some other method to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 3):

Burn supports both `-` and `/` as switch characters. Silent UI mode is supported as `q`, `quiet`, `s`, and `silent` with leading `-` and `/`. See the code at https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/burn/engine/core.cpp#L1098.

Comment: That makes me feel better about the current behaviour :-)